How to get 'underlying' key in shift combinations
In order to implement customisable hotkeys in an application I'm looking for a way to capture and display key presses with modifiers.
What I have now is this customised QLineEdit:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit
from PyQt6.QtGui import QKeyEvent, QKeySequence
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QKeyCombination



class HKLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    modifiers = {16777248, 16777249, 16777250, 16777251}

    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent):
        if event.isAutoRepeat():
            return
        if event.key() in self.modifiers:
            return
        
        seq = QKeySequence(event.keyCombination())
        self.setText(seq.toString())

        # alternative with native virtual key:
        mods = Qt.KeyboardModifier(event.modifiers())
        nv_key = Qt.Key(event.nativeVirtualKey())
        seq = QKeySequence(QKeyCombination(mods, nv_key))
        self.setText(seq.toString())
        

app = QApplication([])
window = HKLineEdit()
window.show()
app.exec()

This works fine but it's not completely perfect for Shift-combinations.
For example Shift+2 is displayed as Shift+@
Is there a (cross-platform, cross-locale) way to display Shift-combinations with the 'base key' instead of the actual key?
Because it sounded appropriate I've tried to use event.nativeVirtualKey() and that gives the desired result for alphanumeric keys, but for other keys the results are very unexpected. For example , gives ¼, and ' gives Þ with my standard US keyboard on Win10.
Please note that beyond the descriptive name I have no idea what a 'native virtual key' actually is and I couldn't find an explanation.

There's no reliable cross-platform way to un-shift a key. Your example code doesn't work at all on my Linux system (with a UK keyboard) - it produces the text Shift+", regardless of whether native-virtual-key is used or not. To understand why, see: Keyboard Layout Issues. For a Windows-only solution, see: Get original key as though without shift modifier and MapVirtualKeyA.

PS: there's also QKeySequenceEdit, which is available in Qt Designer. For me, this also produces e.g. Shift+" for Shift+2, but I don't know how it behaves on other platforms.

@ekhumoro, Thanks for the info and for pointing to QKeySequenceEdit. For me it shows @ for Shift+2, so also not ideal.

@mahkitah Adding to what ekhumoro already pointed out, getting a reliable "key" is extremely difficult. Shortly put, Qt does not allow that, because it works with many abstraction layers that prevent that capability. You cannot alrely on the "virtual key", as it may be unreliable (or unavailable). Depending on the platform, you may need to find out how the OS maps the scan codes based on the current layout, but it's still possible that some intermediate abstraction level (a driver) will be in the middle: you may even get a proper key event that was just synthesized.

@mahkitah Yet, there's still some level of fixing this. As long as you're sure that the user is using a standard keyboard, you can work with known scancodes, which are relatively standard (at least, in theory). For instance, the numbers above letters usually have scancodes starting from 10 ("1") to 19 ("0"). Yet, that's just an assumption based on many aspects. For instance, it's common in Switzerland to have a QWERTZ layout, but many use the QWERTY one anyway even if keys don't match, meaning that you'll probably get the same scancode for Y or Z depending on the current keyboard layout.

@musicamante, I'm 95% sure that I'm going to use the QKeySequenceEdit. Being designed for this purpose it's probably the best compromise across platforms, and the app in question will be used by people all over the world so there's no way of knowing what platforms or keyboard layouts will be used.
